# count selected radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to compute number of radio buttons when selected. by default all radio buttons are checked (n/a), and I only want to count when other value, in this case (good, bad) that can be counted. If for instance, in A, if "good" is selected and then "bad" is selected, it should be counted as 1. "n/a" is not counted.

below is my code.

```
<div>

  <p>A</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="w" value="1">good</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="w" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="w" value="1" checked>n/a</label>

  <p>B</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="x" value="1">good</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="x" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="x" value="1" checked>n/a</label>

  <p>C</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="y" value="1">god</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="y" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="y" value="1" checked>n/a</label>

  <p>D</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="z" value="1">good</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="z" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="z" value="1" checked>na</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include any attempt you have made.  Otherwise the question can come across as a coding request.

Comment: Otherwise, selecting all the radio buttons and then filtering on the `checked` property is fairly straight forward.  EDIT: granted your criteria specifies that you want to ignore those of `n/a`, but there is currently nothing about those radio buttons that signify that they are for `n/a`.  To make the filtering easier, it would be helpful if you could put some class or attribute on them to signify that they were for `n/a`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you count the checked radio buttons. I haven't seen an attempt from you yet, so I'll leave it up to you to figure out how you'd determine whether they're N/A or not.

```js
function count() {
  var sum = 0;
  var radios = $("input[type=radio]");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    sum += radios[i].checked;
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>A</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="w" value="1">good</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="w" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="w" value="1" checked>n/a</label>

  <p>B</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="x" value="1">good</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="x" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="x" value="1" checked>n/a</label>

  <p>C</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="y" value="1">god</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="y" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="y" value="1" checked>n/a</label>

  <p>D</p>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="z" value="1">good</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="z" value="1">bad</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="z" value="1" checked>n/a</label>
</div>
<button onclick="count();">count</button>
```

Comment: `.eq(i)[0]` is a code smell.  If you're going to break the element out of the jQuery object, just use the `[i]`.  Otherwise if you want to keep it in the jQuery object, use `.eq(i).prop('checked')`

Comment: sure, no biggie